# react native with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm doing an android application with the expo framework. I'm a beginner with react native and I need some help to understand a strange behavior.

Why this code is compiling when the second not ? I just add one empty View node.

```js
render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>
      Questionary:
    </Text>
  );
}
```

and this code in not compiling :

```js
render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>
      Questionary:
    </Text>

    <View></View> //because of this !!
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `return` you can have only one node, so you need to wrap all your nodes (`Text`, `View`) with a parent:

```
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>
        Questionary:
      </Text>

      <View></View>
    </View>
  );
```